# jQuery Custom Scrollbar with Isotope Horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jquery-isotope

I'm using the FitColumns layout for Isotope and the jQuery Custom Scrollbar from here: https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar

The implementation works fine, until I filter the content, then I can't get the scrollbar to resize, or reset back to the left.

I have it all in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sP8B9/

```
$(window).load(function () {
var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
$container.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'fitColumns'
});

$('.portfolioFilter a').click(function () {
    $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});

$(window).load(function () {
$(".demo").customScrollbar();
});
//$("your container selector").customScrollbar("resize")
//$("your container selector").customScrollbar("scrollToX", 0) to move the scrollbar to the beginning.
```

At the bottom of the javascript window is the code that is supposed to work to do exactly what I want done above, but I either didn't do it properly, or it needs to be called different. Unfortunately for me I know little to nothing about javascript. The calls are commented out.

If anyone is able to help me solve this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - there is no need to worry about content resize, it's also have few skins you can customize with CSS:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".demo").scrollbar();
});
```

Example of using jQuery Scrollbar in your case http://jsfiddle.net/e4wJG/1/

UPD: strange, example on jsFiddle works only in FF (I think it's because of some jsFiddle restrictions), but if copy code to HTML page, it works well.

Comment: This works well, but the problem with this VS the other scrollbar, is this breaks the Shadowbox js. Not sure why. Shadow box works with the first example, but paired with this solution, both Isotope and Shadowbox don't function properly.